# Having trouble with array in Angular 7

Tags: angular

So, long story short:

I have a dataset that is being stored in sessionStorage, in the format of:

```
[{
    "id": "123:456",
    "streetAddress": "1020 15th St",
    "point": {
      "lati": 35.74633,
      "longi": -101.99677
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "234:567",
    "streetAddress": "123 15th St",
    "point": {
      "lati": 30.2996,
      "longi": -100.9976
    }
  }
]
```

in my service, I am setting:

```
public homeData: any[] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('homes'));
```

in my component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const data = this.searchpropservice.homeData;
    console.log(data);
  }
```

This is working to log the data in my console as an array, however, I am stuck with trying to actually work with any of the data inside of the array. I have tried many different things, with no success.

To make it simple, how would I go about logging each section of JSON data in console as its own data set/array?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your `console.log` output. You should be able to do `data[0].id` to get the `id` of the first array element.

Comment: Thanks! That kicked me out of my funk.... I was doing data.id[0] and not data[0].id. Fail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off topic, but Typescript allows you to add strict typing around your variables. Your `homeData` should be typed as;

```
interface HomeData {
  id: string;
  streetAddress: string;
  point: {
    lati: number;
    longi: number;
  }
}

public homeData: HomeData[] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('homes'));
```

As with my comment above, you should be able to access the first ID in the array with `data[0].id`

You can also traverse the array with;

```
data.forEach(item => {
  console.log('id', item.id);
  console.log('street address', item.streetAddress);
  console.log('point/lati', item.point.lati);
  console.log('point/longi', item.point.lati);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sketchthat in the comments, I was able to solve this.

I just needed to add the [0] to the data attribute, and I was adding it to the id attribute.